# Concatenating only desirable values with LISTAGG

Tags: query, oracle-sql-developer, listagg

In the Oracle DB there is a table with data `"YEARS"`, see a table/image below

```
+-----+-----------+------------------+
| FID |    I0     |       BJA        |
+-----+-----------+------------------+
|   1 |     0     |       1949       |
|   2 |     0     |       1996       |
|   3 |     0     |       1970       |
|   4 |     1     |       1871       |  
|   4 |     0     |       1975       |
|   5 |     0     |       1967       |
|   6 |     0     |       1968       |
|   7 |     0     |       1926       |
|   7 |     1     |       2009       |
|   7 |     2     |       2012       |
|   7 |     3     |       2018       |
|   8 |     0     |       1956       |
|   9 |     0     |       1990       |
|  10 |     0     |       1953       |
|  10 |     1     |       1904       |
| ... |    ...    |       ...        |
+-----+-----------+------------------+
```

[image: snippet_of_table]

I tried to create a fiddle ([here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/20b4a0)), but it did not work ...

```sql
CREATE TABLE YEARS (
    "FID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL, 
    "I0" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL, 
    "BJA" NUMBER(10,0)
);

INSERT ALL
    INTO YEARS ("FID","I0","BJA") VALUES (1,0,1949)
    INTO YEARS ("FID","I0","BJA") VALUES (2,0,1996)
    INTO YEARS ("FID","I0","BJA") VALUES (3,0,1970)
    INTO YEARS ("FID","I0","BJA") VALUES (4,1,1871)
    INTO YEARS ("FID","I0","BJA") VALUES (4,0,1975)
    INTO YEARS ("FID","I0","BJA") VALUES (5,0,1967)
    INTO YEARS ("FID","I0","BJA") VALUES (6,0,1968)
    INTO YEARS ("FID","I0","BJA") VALUES (7,0,1926)
    INTO YEARS ("FID","I0","BJA") VALUES (7,1,2009)
    INTO YEARS ("FID","I0","BJA") VALUES (7,2,2012)
    INTO YEARS ("FID","I0","BJA") VALUES (7,3,2018)
    INTO YEARS ("FID","I0","BJA") VALUES (8,0,1956)
    INTO YEARS ("FID","I0","BJA") VALUES (9,0,1990)
    INTO YEARS ("FID","I0","BJA") VALUES (10,0,1953)
    INTO YEARS ("FID","I0","BJA") VALUES (10,1,1904)
    
SELECT 1 FROM dual;
```

I am trying to execute the following query:

```sql
SELECT YEARS.FID,
       MIN(YEARS.BJA) AS "CONSTRYEAR",
       LISTAGG(YEARS.BJA, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY YEARS.BJA ASC) AS "RECONSTRYEAR"
FROM DB.YEARS YEARS
GROUP BY YEARS.FID;
```

And the output of the above query:

[image: snippet_of_result]

However, it is not the result that I want ... Yes, I am reading documentation [source 1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030), [source 2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466), and [source 3](https://modern-sql.com/feature/listagg); and also I have seen related threads [How to use LISTAGG and WHERE together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48390731/how-to-use-listagg-and-where-together) and [How to use Oracle's LISTAGG function with a unique filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355095/how-to-use-oracles-listagg-function-with-a-unique-filter).

How can I get the result looking like this:

```
+-----+-----------+------------------+
| FID | CONSTRUCT |   RECONSTRYEAR   |
+-----+-----------+------------------+
|   1 |      1949 |                  |
|   2 |      1996 |                  |
|   3 |      1970 |                  |
|   4 |      1871 |             1975 |
|   5 |      1967 |                  |
|   6 |      1968 |                  |
|   7 |      1926 | 2009, 2012, 2018 |
|   8 |      1956 |                  |
|   9 |      1990 |                  |
|  10 |      1904 |             1953 |
+-----+-----------+------------------+
```

Where you see that values from `"CONSTRUCT"` column were excluded from `"RECONSTRYEAR"`. I do not understand where do I need to put a `WHERE YEARS.IO != 0` clause in `LISTAGG`, so the lowest year won't be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to achieve the desired output the initial query was split into two, for selecting `"CONSTRYEAR"` and `"RECONSTRYEAR"` separately.

For the `"CONSTRUCT"`:

```sql
SELECT YEARS.FID,
       MIN(YEARS.BJA) CONSTRUCT
FROM YEARS
GROUP BY YEARS.FID;
```

For the `"RECONSTRYEAR"`:

```sql
SELECT YEARS.FID,
       (LISTAGG(YEARS.BJA, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY YEARS.BJA ASC)) RECONSTRYEAR
FROM YEARS
LEFT JOIN (SELECT YEARS.FID,
                  MIN(YEARS.BJA) BJAHR
           FROM YEARS
           GROUP BY YEARS.FID) YEARS_MINBJA ON YEARS_MINBJA.FID = YEARS.FID
WHERE YEARS.BJA != YEARS_MINBJA.BJAHR
GROUP BY YEARS.FID;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a window `MIN()` to find the construction year per `FID` and return it alongside all the details, like this:

```
SELECT
  YEARS.*
, MIN(BJA) OVER (PARTITION BY FID) AS CONSTRYEAR
FROM
  YEARS
```

It would give you an output like this:

| FID | I0 | BJA | CONSTRYEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1949 | 1949 |
| 2 | 0 | 1996 | 1996 |
| 3 | 0 | 1970 | 1970 |
| 4 | 1 | 1871 | 1871 |
| 4 | 0 | 1975 | 1871 |
| 5 | 0 | 1967 | 1967 |
| 6 | 0 | 1968 | 1968 |
| 7 | 0 | 1926 | 1926 |
| 7 | 3 | 2018 | 1926 |
| 7 | 2 | 2012 | 1926 |
| 7 | 1 | 2009 | 1926 |
| 8 | 0 | 1956 | 1956 |
| 9 | 0 | 1990 | 1990 |
| 10 | 0 | 1953 | 1904 |
| 10 | 1 | 1904 | 1904 |

Now you can apply `LISTAGG` to that row set and exclude `BJA` from the aggregation where it matches `CONSTRYEAR`. To exclude a year, you could use a `CASE` expression like this:

```
CASE BJA WHEN CONSTRYEAR THEN NULL ELSE BJA END
```

Or you could use an equivalent `NULLIF` shorthand:

```
NULLIF(BJA, CONSTRYEAR)
```

It works exactly like the `CASE` expression above.

Now you want to put that expression inside `LISTAGG`:

```
LISTAGG(NULLIF(BJA, CONSTRYEAR), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY BJA ASC) AS RECONSTRYEAR
```

Here is the full query:

```
SELECT
  FID
, CONSTRYEAR
, LISTAGG(NULLIF(BJA, CONSTRYEAR), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY BJA ASC) AS RECONSTRYEAR
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      YEARS.*
    , MIN(BJA) OVER (PARTITION BY FID) AS CONSTRYEAR
    FROM
      YEARS
  )
GROUP BY
  FID
, CONSTRYEAR
;
```

Output:

| FID | CONSTRYEAR | RECONSTRYEAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1949 | *null* |
| 2 | 1996 | *null* |
| 3 | 1970 | *null* |
| 4 | 1871 | 1975 |
| 5 | 1967 | *null* |
| 6 | 1968 | *null* |
| 7 | 1926 | 2009, 2012, 2018 |
| 8 | 1956 | *null* |
| 9 | 1990 | *null* |
| 10 | 1904 | 1953 |

Live demos are available:

- [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9f908a/3)
- [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d7c35dcee734379ed40194ef6e9a22f0&hide=3)

Answer (score 1):

Regexp_replace goes a long way:

```
 Regexp_replace( LISTAGG(YEARS.BJA, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY YEARS.BJA ASC),
                   '^[0-9]*(, )?','')
```

See [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=09093f6dea0322257be85efbf7e4e7a6)

Answer (score 0):

```
select fid,
      min(bja)construct
       , listagg(bja_lead,',') within group (order by bja_lead) reconstryear
  from (select t.fid,
               t.bja,              
               lead(t.bja) over(partition by t.fid order by t.bja) bja_lead
          from years t
          ) a
group by fid
```